# If I'm invisible do I get a bonus to my saving throws?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, saving-throw

In any D&D or AD&D game...

Once my character has become invisible, do I get a bonus to any/all saving throws to which I am entitled?

Does this vary by edition?

Feel free to specify for any (though 4e may be inapplicable; but if I'm wrong, go for it!).

Answer (score 22):

In OD&D, I can't find much clarity as to the effects of invisibility at all.

In BECMI, you have a -6 penalty to hit an invisible defender. And you can't see them.  The rest is up to you. Don't see any impact on saving throws. (That -6 may be from the Rules Cyclopedia).

In 1e, you have a -4 penalty to hit an invisible creature and have to detect them with a percentile roll based on your level/HD and Int per the "Detection of Invisibility" table, or they give themselves away in a manner adjudicated by the DM. And,

> Any attacks incur the -4 penalty of attacking on
>   invisible opponent, of course, and the invisible creature likewise is
>   entitled to +4 on saving throws. *- 1e DMG, p. 60*

In 2e, you have a -4 penalty to hit an invisible defender and have to detect them by a save vs. spell, which lets you know their general vicinity. No saving throw effects I can find.

In 3e/3.5e/Pathfinder, an invisible target has total concealment and therefore enemies have a 50% miss chance, and they have to use Perception to target you in the first place if it's a targeted effect.  There is no modifier to saving throws. (Cover, not concealment, gives Reflex save bonuses.)

In 4e, an invisible target has total concealment and therefore enemies have a -5 to their attack rolls, and they have to use Perception to target you in the first place if it's a targeted effect.  In 4e, magical attacks are against various defenses, saving throws are only for ending ongoing conditions, so no, invisibility doesn't affect saves, but it does affect the mechanic which does what saves did in earlier editions.

So I guess in short - "Only in 1e."

Answer (score 4):

**In 4e, it's harder to affect someone with spells.**

Yes, if we consider saving throws in context of all four editions. The purpose of a saving throw (not a 4e save, but in general) is to answer a question: does this spell affect me?

Therefore, as saving throws transformed into defenses in 4e, and invisibility provides total oncealment for (an effective) +5 to saving throws (technically it's a penalty to the enemy's to-hit rolls).

From an internal 4e context: "does this spell continue to effect me as a save-ends effect?" The answer is usually no.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, save vs breath weapon could give you a +4 bonus to your roll. A breath weapon attack is essentially suppressive fire as described in Cyberpunk's FNF rules, and would be affected by a monster not being able to see you.

Similarly, a save vs rod/staff/wand in which you're trying to be targetted would afford you that +4 bonus.

Any other spell that conceivably needs to be targetted to affect you, but is avoided with a saving throw rather than being handled with an attack roll would be affected by invisibility.

This would obviously no longer be true in 3e or later, which gets very specific in its rulings.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this?

Comment: Granted, my 2e knowledge is a little thing, but wouldn't aimed magical effects have a to-hit with the -4 bonus already lumped in?  Therefore no bonus to save due to invisibility?

Answer (score -2):

I can only answer for 3rd and 4th.  No, no extra bonus on your saves.  I would assume the same of previous editions.